# Ternary operator inside $gt

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The problem that I have encountered with the following piece of code is that the $cond operator seems to  not work. When i replace it completely  with the value 8, it works like a charm. Note: I am just trying to see how $cond works with $gt. Eventually the boolean condition will be related to the date field inside $group(I will try to check if the date is of a working day or not).

```
db.getCollection("intervals-time").aggregate([
    {
            $addFields: {
                convertedTime: {
                    $toDouble: "$time"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id:  {
                    personid: "$personid",
                    date: {
                        month: { $month: "$date" },
                        day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },
                        year: { $year: "$date"}
                    }
                },
                total: {
                    $sum: "$convertedTime"
                },

            }
        },
        {
            $match: { total: { $gt : {$cond:[true,8,5]}}}

        }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) to achieve that

```
{ "$match": { "$expr": { "$gt": ["$total", { "$cond": [true, 8, 5] }] }}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use $cond inside a $match operator. $match is only used to filter out documents, while using $cond you are setting/changing some value based on some condition. $cond can be used inside a $project operation and not $match.